# Network organization with VMWare Server 2

Tags: networking, vmware-server

I am not a System Administrator, but
I have a task:

Exists server with local ip adress (Host A).
On Host A installed VMWare Server 2.0.

I have 4 VM on this server:

1) Oracle DB Server 1

2) Oracle DB Server 2

3) Oracle App Server (WebLogic)

4) VCS Server (SVN, Mercurial)

I need to make transparent access to this servers. I mean for DB servers using TNS, for App Server this is HTTP access to App Server Console and for SVN using clients.

I see 2 simple solutions:

1) Use port forwarding

2) Use VMWare Console

Maybe somebody know good solution or have ideas how to get access more convinient without RDP, VNC if this is possible.

PS: In the near future on Host A will be installed vSphere Hypervisor.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you configure your VMware Server's networking to use bridged networking then the VM's can be given direct (which is what I assume you mean by transparent access) to whichever networks the host server has physical access to. You can find an overview of VMware Server Networking options in [this article on carbonwind.net.](http://www.carbonwind.net/VMware/VMwareServerNetworkingOptions/VMwareServerNetworkingOptions.htm)

If you choose to move to the vSphere Hypervisor (ESXi) you will have to provide access in a similar way - in that case the mechanism uses virtual switches managed by the hypervisor that you configure with the appropriate physical uplinks (ie NIC mappings) that enable connectivity to the required external physical networks.

Once configured in this way VM's on either system will be directly accessible from the network - your choice of protocol via these network, for console or application access, depends on whatever such protocols your VM supports (RDP\VNC ..).

For out-of-band access to the VM's console you also have the option of connecting via the hypervisors management console. VMware Server supports VNC access ( as detailed in [this article on petri.co.il](http://www.petri.co.il/virtual_using_vnc_and_vmware_server.htm)) but as far as I'm aware ESXi only supports VI Client access when in stand alone mode. You can provide HTTP(S) access to the VM's console for ESXi hosts if they are part of a vCenter managed cluster. In either case performance will almost certainly not be as good as an in-band remote console protocol from within the Guest VM. Access in these cases will (initially) be via the address of the VMware Server server or via the vCenter server and not the address(es) of the Guest VM's.